# When in Fullscreen OSX Yosemite won't hide the dock

Tags: macos, dock, fullscreen

I don't have "auto hide" enable for dock. In all previous version dock, it will hide if I enter in full screen mode for VLC player or for chrome. Now that's no longer the case.

If I enable "auto hide", then it hides it but that's not what I am looking for as I like to see dock all the time except full screen mode.

Comment: Does the dock not hide for just some  of your apps or all of them. I dod not have VLC on this Mac but all my app including Chrome hide the dock when in FS.

Comment: None of the app. Even for chrome it doesn't hide.

Comment: Same thing happens for me as well, it's irritating, and usually it's when I can't restart because I'm in a webex or goto meeting or doing something for work that needs to be done.

Answer (score 17):

Open [Terminal](http://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac-software/how-use-terminal-on-mac-3608274/) and type:

```
killall Dock
```

This will restart the process.

Comment: When I do it it says: -bash: $: command not found

Comment: @JeffreyShwe Don't type the `$`, that's just the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

When facing this kind of problem (it occurs for me especially when I'm playing), I usually  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>  +  <kbd>Tab</kbd>  to *switch to another* application, then *switch back* to my full-screened one through the same command. It does the trick and makes the Dock disappear.

Comment: I tried that. The Dock is still there.